# Readfile is not reading the the blank spaces from my text file?

Tags: c++

I am reading in a text file and have found that it will not print the blank characters between the words. I want to read each character a character at a time and then print the character to the output window. The read will read the file but does not show the blank spaces and I have not been able to find out why the blank spaces are being skipped.

**Question: Why is my read not reading the blank characters in my test file?**

When i find a blank character I want to print the word Blank Space.

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

void readTestFile()
{
    char ch;
    std::fstream fin("C:/Users/itpr13266/Desktop/myTest.txt", std::fstream::in);
    while (fin >> ch) {
        std::cout << "Letter: " << ch << std::endl;
          if (ch == ' ')  <-- should catch a blank spaces
          {
              std::cout << "Blank Space" << std::endl;
          }
          else  <-- Just write the letter
          {
              std::cout << ch << std::endl; 
          }
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   readTestFile();

   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Test File:

```
  This is testing for fprintf...
  This is testing for fputs...
```

Output

```
 Letter: T
 T
 Letter: h
 h
 ...etc...
```

Comment: Your sample output does not even show the problem. What happens when it gets to the first space? It may be useful to print out the integer value of `ch` as well.

Comment: This operation `fin >> ch` parses on whitespace. It *deliberately* does not grab whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard input function `istream::operator>>()` skips all leading whitespace before performing input. If you need to obtain spaces, there are a couple options you can use:

- **`std::noskipws`**

  By setting the `std::ios_base::noskipws` flag, the stream will not discard leading whitespace and `ch` will be given the value of each consecutive character. Note that this succeeds only with the overload that takes a `char` (`ch` will be given the value of the space). For any other data type this will not work:

  ```c++
  while (fin >> std::noskipws >> ch)
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- **`std::istream::get()`**

  `get()` is an UnformattedInputFunction function, and thus will not parse the input beforehand.

  ```c++
  while (fin.get(ch))
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- **`std::istreambuf_iterator<>`**

  You can also use iterators to work directly with the buffer. `std::istreambuf_iterator<>` also doesn't parse the input:

  ```c++
  std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{fin},
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
            std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>{std::cout},
  ```

Comment: Will it really not work for <em>any</em> other data type? I didn't try, but I'd think that for `string` it should also succeed (although possibly not with the intended result).

Comment: @celtschk It won't work unless you clear the whitespace yourself. [Even with `std::string` it doesn't work](http://ideone.com/77Mbkn).

Comment: OK, I tried and g++ agrees with you. However I'm quite surprised, as I would have expected it to successfully read an empty string (btw, your ideone does not test for success or failure, only that the string is empty, which for a successful read would also be the case).

Comment: @celtschk It can't because whitespace is a delimiter for input with the formatted operators. You can use `std::getline()` and it will work. (Re. If you check the state of the stream for `good()` it will return false because 0 characters were extracted into `str`, causing `failbit` to be set in the stream state.)

Comment: An empty string *is* a valid value for `std::string`, and the input stream contains an empty string followed by a delimiter (which means the first character is a delimiter).

Comment: @celtschk But there *is* no empty string followed by a delimiter. Those are just four consecutive space characters. And while an empty string is a valid value for an `std::string`, that is **not** what's being extracted into `str` - the extractor for `std::string` first *clears* the string, and then attempts the input (which it ultimately fails since the first available character is the delimiter).

Comment: There is *always* an empty string at *any* position in a character sequence. The only reason why the read fails is that (I now looked on cppreference, and it's indeed standard) the function explicitly sets `failbit` if no characters are read (which means reading an empty string is explicitly considered a failure). But it would be logically more consistent to consider that as successfully reading an empty string. Note that at this point I'm not arguing what the function *does* (that one is cleared by now), but what would be the logical thing (and what I therefore expected).

Comment: @celtschk I was mistaken in my last comment. I meant to say what you said - that it fails because no characters are extracted. But I do not understand what you mean by that there is a an always an empty string at any position in the character sequence. So if a stream has the characters `"abc"` you're saying that there is an empty string between each character? Can you please explain?

Comment: Sure. Let's first look at the constant for an empty string. In C and C++, the content is delimited by quotes at the beginning and end. So what does the emty string look like? You know it: `""`. YOu see, after the initial quote (delimiter) directly follows the final quote (delimiter). The *empty string* is in between the two quotes, which follow directly on each other, because the emty string has no characters. Also look at the C representatn. That is the sequence of characters, *followed* by the delimiter `'\0'`. So what is the representation of the empty string? Well, the characters of the …

Comment: … empty string followed by the delimiter. Which means, the first character is the delimiter (that is, *exactly* as in the stream case). Now consider the concatenation of strings, where e.g. the first string is `"a"`, the second string is empty, and the third string is `"b"`. So what is the concatenation? Well, `"ab"`. So clearly there's an empty string between the a and the b in `"ab"` (we explicitly put it there!). And of course that is true also before the a and after the b. That is, there's an empty string (or two, or a million) between any two characters of a string.

Comment: @celtschk I have to disagree fully with what you claim. There is **no** empty string between each character.

Comment: And your argument? And what's wrong with mine in your opinion?

Comment: @celtschk Well if there was an empty string between each character (and as you say each empty string is technically `"\0"`) that would cut short each character by its first byte. Meaning `"abc"` is `"a\0b\0c\0"` which of course is unrealistic.

Comment: No, the empty string is *not* `\0` (the `\0` in C and C++ is a delimiter which is *not* part of the string, although it is part of the representation). If the delimiter were part of the string, then the concatenation of `a` and `b` would be `a\0b`. In the zero-terminated representation, the empty string (just as any other string) consists of the characters *before* the `\0` delimiter. Which, in the case of the empty string, is none at all. That's the defining characteristic of the empty string: It contains *no* characters. None at all. Not a single one.

Comment: Also note that the `\0` delimiter only exists in that specific representation; it doesn't exist e.g. in the Turbo Pascal representation of the very same string.

Comment: @celtschk We're discussing C/C++, and in those languages a string literal const char[] always has a null byte at the end and it is always always part of the string. It follows that an empty string will have the null byte as well. There cannot be an empty string between each character. Let's continue this discussion here - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50277/room-for-0x499602d2-and-celtschk

Answer (score 1):

You are performing formatted input, use unformatted input

```
std::fstream::traits_type::int_type ch;
while((ch = fin.get()) != std::fstream::traits_type::eof()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I like more `char ch; while ( fin.get(ch) ) {...}`. Not just _eof_ is tested in this way.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `operator>>` on streams skips any leading whitespace before parsing the value. This is, for example, what allows you to read the input `30 60 95` with `int i,j,k; fin >> i >> j >> k;` (otherwise reading `j` would fail because after the `30`, there follows a space, not an integer).

You now have two options if you want to read the spaces as well:

1. (preferred): Use the member function `get()` for unformatted reading of a character.
2. Instruct the stream not to eat whitespace before reading: `fin >> std::noskipws >> ch`.

Comment: Does the get() just return one character?

Comment: @user3376708: Well, that depends on which overload you call ;-) The one without parameter will return either one character, or EOF. The one taking a reference to char will read one character, if possible, and write that to its argument. The other overloads read until they encounter a certain delimiter (either `'\n'`, or passed as argument), or exceed the given size, or cannot read any more characters (EOF or stream error).

Answer (score 0):

Read more about the different [iostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/) methods. In particular, you are using [istream's operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/). Take careful note of how it is designed to work; it uses whitespace as a delimiter and does not store the whitespace.

If you want to read every `char` from your stream (e.g. a file stream), you should not be using `>>`, but rather consider using [istream::get()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/).

```
// stream is an istream, such as cin or ifstream
char ch;
while (ch = stream.get()) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I set it in a function so you can copy paste. It detects the space, and also the change in line. I tried it with ASCII art and it worked fine.

```
void print2()
    {
    char ch;
    std::fstream myStream("GameOver.txt", std::fstream::in);
    while (myStream.get(ch))
        {
            std::cout << ch;        
        }
    }
```